# Join an IEnumerable in C# when the key selector shall return a set of keys

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, lookup

I've a container of data called `Meeting`

```
public struct Meeting
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime Start { get; set; }

    public DateTime End { get; set; }
}
```

This is very simple. It has an Id, and two date times marking the time when this meeting starts and the date time when this meeting end.

I need to return a `Lookup` that for each day maps all the meeting scheduled for that day.
I've implemented this IEnumerable extension:

```
public static IEnumerable<ILookup<D, T>> GroupBy<T, D> (this IEnumerable<T> outer,
                                                        Func<T, IEnumerable<D>> func)
{
        if (outer == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(outer));

        if (func == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(func));

        Dictionary<D, IEnumerable<T>> lookup = new Dictionary<D, IEnumerable<T>>();

        foreach(T item in outer)
        {
            IEnumerable<D> keySelectory = func(item);
            if (keySelectory != null)
            {
                foreach(D newKey in keySelectory)
                {
                    if (!lookup.ContainsKey(newKey))
                    {
                        lookup.Add(newKey, new List<T>() { item });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        List<T> temp = lookup[newKey].ToList();
                        temp.Add(item);
                        lookup[newKey] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return WHAT?
}
```

I'm lost at the end because the Lookup constructor is kept private so I cannot instantiate it.

Because I would like to call something like that:

```
meetings.GroupBy(meeting => GetDatesFromStartAndEndTimes(meeting));
```

where the method GetDatesFromStartAndEndTimes is trivial.
Can anyone tell me how to proceed? Thanks.

Comment: Can a given meeting can belong to multiple days?

Comment: Theoretically yes... If for example a part of the same meeting is scheduled for today and the other part scheduled for tomorrow.

Comment: btw: I think `GroupBy` is a bad name because it hides or gets confused with linq's `GroupBy`

Comment: You can't construct a `Lookup` directly, but you can call `Enumerable.ToLookup`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just wondering how to create a Lookup, you use the LINQ ToLookup extension method:

```
var meetingsByDate = meetings
    .SelectMany(meeting => GetDatesFromStartAndEndTimes(meeting),
        (meeting, date) => new{meeting, date})
    .ToLookup(pair => pair.date, pair.meeting);
```

Comment: Where is `GetDatesFromStartAndEndTimes()` defined?

Comment: @Hogan: It's part of the OP code, so I'd assumed it was already implemented. If not, it would be [simple enough to implement](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jjdOQe).

Comment: Thanks... short and useful without needing an extension. Yes @Hogan I implemented it in a very simple way (foreach DateTime from StartTime and EndTime)

Comment: @user2896152 -- good -- I just wanted to check since it seemed like a gap in the answer.